# Joomla .htm url mapping to pages in CMS

Tags: joomla

I inherited a Joomla site that has a set up I'm not familiar with.   The url of pages on the site are like

```
http://hufboxing.com/about.htm
http://hufboxing.com/training.htm
http://hufboxing.com/schedule.htm
```

I looked in the .htaccess file and do not see any rules that map .htm urls to the Joomla query string urls.

In the CMs, on each article are url alias.  The corresponding URL alias to each of the urls above are:

```
http://hufboxing.com/about-us
http://hufboxing.com/team-training
http://hufboxing.com/the-gym-schedule
```

However, going to any of these alias gives a 404 page.  Even if I attach a .htm extension to these urls, it gives 404 page.

Where do I go in Joomla to add new pages to the site and add new .htm urls?

Here is the website: 
http://www.hufboxing.com

Comment: Do you have any SEF plugin?

Comment: Hi Unykvis, here is the website: http://www.hufboxing.com .  I do not see an SEF plugin installed, or any other plugin for SEO urls.

Comment: Well it that Joomla is .php why is it showing .htm in the URL? Do you know why?

Comment: I do not know why.  And that's what I'm trying to figure out. Even when I go to the CMS, I go into the Schedule article, I see that the alias is "huf-gym-schedule".  But going to http://www.hufboxing.com/huf-gym-schedule gives me a page not found.

Comment: Is this a windows server or linux?

Comment: It is a linux based server

Comment: That is normal. They are based on your article and menu aliases. Joomla uses a database to store the text so you won't find pages.  How do you want the urls to look?  Also what version?

Comment: You will find the sef plugin in the plugin manager and sef settings in the global configuration. Don't mess with the pouting just the settings :).

Answer (score 0):

That is normal. They are based on your article and menu aliases. Joomla uses a database to store the text so you won't find pages.  How do you want the urls to look?  Also what version?  To add pages login to administrator and go to create article. Then you may want to go to the menu manager and link. I recommend you review the beginner docs at http://docs.joomla.org.

Comment: Is it normal to have .htm in the URL? Can you explain to me this, because in my case I never had my URL like this example. Just want to learn this for future reference.

Comment: In global configuration you can pick a suffix (htm or html usually) or  leave it blank and don't have one.

Comment: HI Elin, i updated my question to show that the alias did not solve my problem.  It's as if alias are not used at all.

Comment: What are the 1. item aliases and 2. Menu aliases for the items reached by the above urls?  I'm not sure what problem it is you are trying to solve?
 OH OH OH  Are you confused because the menu aliases are replacing the article aliases? Menus override artcle, o if you want them to match the titles rather than the text of the menu link you need to type the aliaes by hand instead of letting them autogenerate.